# Add Captcha to Comment Form

Tags: 8, captcha

How can the reCAPTCHA module be applied to a node's comment field in Drupal 8?

This particular node has a comment field added with the machine name `field_story_comments`.

That field is a custom comment type with the machine name `resource_comments`.

I have tried to add both `field_story_comments` and `resource_comments` under `/admin/config/people/captcha/captcha-points`, but am not seeing any CAPTCHA for that nodes' comment field.

Comment: when you view it when not logged in as admin does it show ?

Comment: Have you configured it to omit challenges once successfully answered? You'll have to delete those captcha cookies to test that the form appears when it should or Always add a challenge when testing.

Comment: Additionally you can use the option **Add CAPTCHA administration links to forms** of the Captcha module temporarily. Visit the form, you'll see the button to add the captcha challenge, add it, then turn off the option once your comment form appears on the captcha list in configuration.